# I have to pass slug as well as other parameters to retrieve information but i want to hide parameters showing in url using .htaccess except slug

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have to pass slug as well as other parameters to retrieve information but i want to hide parameters showing in url except slug.
I have tried a lot with .htaccess but its still not giving me positive results.

Actual url is something like this 
http://localhost/qa1/reply.php?user_id=69%20&ans_id=44%20&id=71%20&post_url=what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process

I want to convert this into
http://localhost/qa1/reply/69/44/71/what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process

This is the code from where i pass the parameters to reply.php page.

```
echo "<a href='reply.php?user_id=$user_id &ans_id=$ans_id &id=$id &post_url=$post_url'>view replies</a>";
```

And what I did in .htaccess below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^reply/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) reply.php?user_id=$2&ans_id=$3&id=$4&post_url=$5
```

Nothing is showing except a blank white screen.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Well, we cannot say anything about a white screen, you will need to debug your application logic which we don't know anything about. Best option is to start monitoring your http server's error log file. That is where you can typically read what the actual issue is your code run's into.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha i was actually starting the parameters from $2 to $5 when i changed it from $1 to $4 now its working perfectly. Now i want to redirect this RewriteRule which i am trying like                                                               RewriteRule ^reply/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) reply.php?user_id=$1&ans_id=$2&id=$3&post_url=$4 [R=301,L]
    
But its shwoing the same old url without hiding parameters.

Comment: It is unclear what you are now trying to do. If you "redirect" the browser it will load the target URL you send it to, so that one with the GET arguments in the query string, which is not what you want. So the question is: why do you want to redirect?

Comment: When I wrote this RewriteRule then I went to my browser and pasted this http://localhost/qa1/reply/69/44/71/what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process so it was showing the same results which my browser was showing for this url http://localhost/qa1/reply.php?user_id=69%20&ans_id=44%20&id=71%20&post_url=what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process.

Comment: But when I open my website it showing me this url http://localhost/qa1/reply.php?user_id=69%20&ans_id=44%20&id=71%20&post_url=what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process I don’t want to show this url anymore I want this url http://localhost/qa1/reply/69/44/71/what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process

Comment: You need to separate rewriting and redirection, since they need to oeprate in oposite directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it might make sense to summarize a bit in an answer. Especially after you comment asking about the redirection. You need to separate rewriting and redirection, since they need to oeprate in oposite directions:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user_id=(\d+)&ans_id=(\d+)&id=(\d+)&post_url=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^reply\.php$ reply/%1/%2/%3/%4 [R=301,QSD]

RewriteRule ^reply/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ reply.php?user_id=$2&ans_id=$3&id=$4&post_url=$5 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a http-302 redirection and only change that to a http-301 once everything works fine. That way you prevent caching issues while still developing...

Comment: Thanks @arkascha Sir you are guiding me very well. I just copy your above code in my htaccess file but after testing its showing me the same old url like http://localhost/qa1/reply.php?user_id=69%20&ans_id=44%20&id=71%20&post_url=what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process      Can you please explain about the changes if need to make here so i will try.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not take the path into account, in your test the rule did not get applied at all. I modifed the answer such that the full path is considered.

Comment: And another thing: the localhost URL you used for testing does _not_ match what you claimed in your question. The values for `user_id` and `ans_id` are _not_ numeric as you claimed but contain other stuff: `http://localhost/qa1/reply.php?user_id=69%20&ans_id=44%20&id=71%20&post_url=what-is-the-best-example-of-agile-process`. The `%20` is a blank (space character) that is encoded. You do not want that in your URL. Where does that come from? You want to fix the reference, not the rule to match the faulty URL.

Comment: Sir I have removed the blank spaces now it’s not showing %20 in url. I am glad to see changes you made in your answer. I tried with the changes you made but I am getting old url showing all parameters with values. I am using PHP 5.7. I think it’s something wrong in my local server. But htaccess works fine if I put garbage then it’s show 505 error.

Comment: I rechecked the rules given above, they look fine to me. Where is that dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") located in your server side file system?

Comment: .htaccess file is located in qa1 directory. It’s same directory where other files are stored

Comment: Ah, ok, that explains. Usually such files are kept in the http server's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. But that is just one of the many many problems such files create. Usually it is the _much_ better idea to palce such rules in the real http server's host configuration, if you have access to that. .htaccess style files are only a cheap replacement for that that comes with lots of disadvantages.

Comment: I changed matching patterns and target back to relative paths, that should work in this case.